# How to remove remote repos's directory after I add this directory into .gitignore?

Tags: git

In the beginning, I dont put `logs/` into .gitignore, so after a `git push`, `logs/` appears in remote, then I add `logs/` in .gitignore and do a commit and push, but `logs/` still remains in remote, how do I remove `logs/` in remote ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.gitignore` ignores untracked files, but once files were added into a repo, they will be tracked until explicitly removed.

If you don't care keep the directory in history, then you just need to remove it from the git `git rm -r logs`, `git commit`. However, if the directory is very large and significantly increases repository size, then follow the advice from Yan Zax to `filter-branch`.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is to use `$git filter-branch`. For more details take a look at:

http://git-scm.com/book/ch6-4.html#The-Nuclear-Option:-filter-branch

and

https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data